Reversing the implication of Gagliardo-Nirenberg-Sobolev inequality
Suppose $u : \mathbb{R}^N \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ satisfies $u \in L^{p^*}(\mathbb{R}^N)$, $\nabla u \in L^p(\mathbb{R}^N)$, where $1 \le p < N$ and $p^*$ is the Sobolev conjugate of $p$. Does it follow that $u \in W_0^{1, p}(\mathbb{R}^N)$?

No. Here is an example.
Define $u:\mathbb R^d \to \mathbb R$ by
$$
u(x) = \max(1, |x|)^s.
$$
Then
$$
u \in L^p \quad \Leftrightarrow \quad sp + d< 0  \quad \Leftrightarrow \quad
\frac1{sp} > -\frac1d
$$
and
$$
\nabla u \in L^p \quad \Leftrightarrow \quad (s-1)p + d< 0  \quad \Leftrightarrow \quad
\frac1{(s-1)p} > -\frac1d.
$$
In addition, with $\frac1{p^*} = \frac1p - \frac1d$, we have
$$
u \in L^{p^*} \quad \Leftrightarrow \quad sp^* + d< 0  \quad \Leftrightarrow \quad
\frac1{sp^*} =  \frac1s( \frac1p - \frac1d) > -\frac1d.
$$
Let $d>1$ and $ 1\le p<d$ be given.
With the choice
$$
s = -\frac d{p^*} - \frac12 = - \frac dp+\frac 12
$$
we have
$$
u \in L^{p^*}, \ \nabla u \in L^p, \ u\not \in L^p.
$$

Very nice, thanks!
